Powershell IF loop not contiuning
I have the following code and I am expecting my mini program to display the value number one, stop the service and then display the value number two.
I have checked the documentation here and it confirms the next command should execute after the true/false from the IF statement has been executed.
https://www.pdq.com/blog/how-to-use-if-statements-in-powershell/
$AccServiceName = 'AccountLoaderService'
$AccService = Get-service $AccServiceName

if ($AccService.Status -eq 'Running')
{
    Write-Host '1'
    Stop-Service $AccServiceName
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 20

if ($AccService.Status -eq 'Stopped')
{
    Write-Host '2'
}

What actually happens is, it displays the number one, but never number 2.
The service definitelly stops within the 20 seconds specified and if I run the command again straight afterwards, without the sleep statment included it returns the number 2 value.
Hope that makes sense, any help greatly appreciated.

$AccServiceName = 'AccountLoaderService'
$AccService = Get-Service $AccServiceName

if ($AccService.Status -eq 'Running') {
    Write-Host '1'
    Stop-Service $AccServiceName
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 20

# Refresh the service status
$AccService = Get-Service $AccServiceName

if ($AccService.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
    Write-Host '2'
}

By adding $AccService = Get-Service $AccServiceName after the Start-Sleep command, you ensure that the status of the service is updated before checking it again. This should allow your script to display ‘2’ as expected.
